# What index should I create for this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if i need to create an index with multiple columns or an index for each of the columns used.

I am also not sure whether to use desc or asc on the field indexed

```
SELECT  * from movie 
where year > 1892 AND year < 2015 AND  genre like '%Adventure%'  AND  genre like '%Comedy%'  
AND  genre like '%Mystery%'  AND imdbRating > 5.9 AND imdbvotes > 99 AND type = 'movie'
```

genre is a varch and looks like 'action, comedy, horror,

Comment: `year` and `genre` seems most obvious.

Comment: @hd why are they more important then imdbrating and imdbvotes?

Comment: `'%Adventure%'` cannot benefit from an index, FYI. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @ceejayoz what part of that page explains why genre can't benefit?

Comment: @code578841441 _The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character._

Comment: 1. See normalisation

Comment: make type an integer id, genre a one-to-many relation, then you can put indexes there. as of now, year imdbrating and imdbvotes are best candidates

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossible to answer well. The reasonableness of index creation results from the data that we draw from the query. The index should be created for the columns of the table, which query did not use more than 10-15% of the rows, then it applies the optimization. In this regard, see which of the columns meets this condition, and create an index on it.

Comment: 'which query did not use more than 10-15% of the rows' please explain moremore

Comment: If you have a column eg. 1000 lines, and as a result you get a selection of about 150 lines then it makes sense to impose the index. Otherwise it will speed up your queries

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of additional information: (year,type,imdbrating,imdbvotes)